# How to reference a register in an ex command

Tags: external-command, macro, register, ex-mode, expression-register

I'm trying to write what I thought would be a simple macro to take some values that have been yanked into some registers (a & b) and use `bc` to do some addition with those values.

Here is the expression/part I'm stuck on...

```
:let @c=trim(system("echo '@a + @b' | bc"))
```

if I replace those `@a` and `@b` references with the register contents manually then the expression/command works as expected.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By putting `@a` and `@b` inside the quotes you're preventing Vim from evaluating them so you're really just passing the literal strings "@a" and "@b".

Pull them out of the quotes and build a Vim string using the concatenation operator...

```
:let @c=trim(system("echo '" . @a . " + " . @b . "' | bc"))
```

So if `@a` and `@b` contain, for example, 2 and 3, respectively, then you're passing the string

```
echo '2 + 3' | bc
```

to the `system()` function as you intended.

Alternatively, you can use `printf()` to build the string:

```
:let @c=trim(system(printf("echo '%s + %s' | bc", @a, @b)))
```

A lot of people prefer this to having a bunch of concat operators.

In both cases `@a` and `@b` are exposed so they get evaluated as Vim expressions and, thus, resolve to the contained values.

Comment: Thanks for answer, worked a charm!

I'd tried a similar expression earlier, but was using the wrong concatenation operator, +'s instead of the .'s

Comment: Aha! You're not the first to do that, I'm sure. :) Check out the update. `printf()` is considered nicer by many. It works similarly to `printf` in shells and programming languages.